# json decode of url request which contain special character

Tags: php, json

I have a url request like this:

`http://localhost/pro/api/index/update_profile?data={"id":"51","name":"abc","address":"stffu fsagu asfhgui fsahgiu3#$@^^@#%^3 6\"\"wkgforqf\";rqgjrg..,,,rqwgtr''qwrgtrw'trwqt'rqwtqwr trqt\n"}`

I am trying to json decode of this url.I use following code to decode url.It is working perfect if url not contain special character. but how to decode it if it contains special character.

```
    $string = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $jsonFix = urldecode($string);
    $string = htmlentities($jsonFix, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
    $json = json_decode($string, true);
    print_r($json);exit;
```

I tried this code but it is not working.when i am try following:

> print_r($_REQUEST['data']);exit;

output is:

> {"id":"51","name":"ds"","address":"stffu fsagu asfhgui fsahgiu3

means it is bracking from `#` character.
(sidenote: i am working on api for iphone so request came from iphone,framework:CI)

so how to get url which contain special character and how to decode it?

Comment: Hashtag can't be sent through Get parameter.

Comment: i don't know, how iphone developer send data. but i can get it using `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @sriraman It can, just needs to be `urlencode()`ded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating the `$data` in some ways that aren't really necessary. `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` make sense if applied to specific values - not the whole JSON. The danger is that they mess up the JSON, it is only important here to `urldecode()`!

```
$jsonFix = urldecode($data);
$json = json_decode($jsonFix, true);
```

This [already works](http://3v4l.org/TtY8S) and doesn't leave any character out.

If you plan to post something of that and want to escape it, you can do it like so

```
htmlspecialchars($json['address'], ENT_QUOTES)
```

Comment: oops sorry..it's breking.i use `$data = urlencode($_REQUEST['data']);
        print_r($data);exit;`  if i remove # then it is working.

Comment: Is it encoded properly (as suggested by [user2428118](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24180123/1557526))?

Comment: actually the request came for iPhone so i have no idea.i am trying to fix in server side.

Comment: @DS9 You can paste the request in your question, `var_dump($_REQUEST['data']);` and look at source code

Answer (score 3):

[The `#` character marks the beginning of the fragment part of the URL.](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

You need to properly URL-encode the URL for this to work.

For example, your JSON, when correctly URL-encoded, becomes:

```
%7B%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22abc%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22stffu%20fsagu%20asfhgui%20fsahgiu3%23%24%40%5E%5E%40%23%25%5E3%206%5C%22%5C%22wkgforqf%5C%22%3Brqgjrg..%2C%2C%2Crqwgtr%27%27qwrgtrw%27trwqt%27rqwtqwr%20trqt%5Cn%22%7D
```

The entire URL becomes:

```
http://localhost/pro/api/index/update_profile?data=%7B%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22abc%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22stffu%20fsagu%20asfhgui%20fsahgiu3%23%24%40%5E%5E%40%23%25%5E3%206%5C%22%5C%22wkgforqf%5C%22%3Brqgjrg..%2C%2C%2Crqwgtr%27%27qwrgtrw%27trwqt%27rqwtqwr%20trqt%5Cn%22%7D
```

Check the documentation of your language of choice to find the correct method for URL-encoding characters.

For example, in PHP, this is [`rawurlencode`](//www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) and in JavaScript this is [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

If necessary, there are also plenty of URL coders online, such as [this website](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just replace the "#" character with something like "&hashtagChar;" before you process, and put it back afterwards?

Comment: the request came from iphone so ican't replace it.

Comment: Who says that this char will be the only one not making it through the process? Also in a proper set up system it shouldn't really be a problem